# dynamically changing html text before loading- possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many flow charts and clicking on each block of a flow chart must open a question. Basically the question page has the same template with just a change in the heading. Now I think it would be absurd to create a html file for each question since the template is going to remain exactly the same. Once the user clicks on a block of the flow chart, is there a way to change the heading of the question page and then load it?

I want to use jquery to do it and I am just a beginner in jquery. I know how to change texts by appending/replacing elements once the page has been displayed or loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace it each time on the fly:

```
var template = "{header}<p>Some text</p>";
$('#output').append(template.replace('{header}', 'Some header'));
$('#output').append(template.replace('{header}', 'New header'));
```

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ykmtF/